# How to determine if a View has a specific control

Tags: mvvm, caliburn.micro

Consider the following xaml:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="UiRoot"/>
</UserControl>
```

Now, in the ViewModel, I have a reference to the view (from Caliburn.Micro OnViewLoaded).  I then need to determine if the View has a Grid named UiRoot.

```
protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view) {
        base.OnViewLoaded(view);
    //Does the view have a UiRoot?
}
```

This code is actually in the ViewModelBase, and sometimes the View will have a UiRoot, and sometimes not.  It is used to dynamically create the view when it does exist.

My first thought was to create an IHasUiRoot interface and put it in the codebehind.  Then I could cast it to IHasUiRoot.  This works, but since I have an otherwise empty Codebehind, I would like to keep it that way and do it through reflection or some other way. In the end, I need a reference to the actual control in order to add controls to it dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are implementing an `IViewAware` viewmodel such as Screen you can use the `IViewAware.GetView()` method (in `OnViewLoaded` which I think is `IViewAware` anyway) to get a reference to the view

Then you can use `VisualTreeHelper` or `Control.FindName` to get a reference to the control:

```
var view = this.GetView() as Control;
if(view != null)
{
    var grid = view.FindName("UiRoot") as Grid;

    if(grid != null) // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought: you are adding a kind of dependency on the View in the ViewModel.

One way to solve that is by moving the code to the View; let it examine itself and set a (dependency) property to point to the control UiRoot.

In the ViewModel you could add a similar property and bind these in the view code.

This way you can check/use the property in the ViewModel without adding View dependent code.